# Laravel - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

http://laravel.io/bin/Nk3v#2

I thought I had everything working, until I added this last foreign key to the feedback table.

I can't see anything wrong with it, help?

Line 31 is the issue apparently?

The table type is innodb running MariaDB 10.0.8. Several other foreign keys are set successfully earlier in the same way. The table the FK references does exist before this one tries to be set.

Looked at most of the answers of similar on here, no fix so far. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I had not set the foreign key to `unsigned()`.

Answer (score 2):

if everything is ok, just add `->unsigned();` at the end of `foregin key`.